# Order result by existence of specific contents

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a mysql table, that contains entries with ID, language and text. There is always one ID-language pair, but there can be more IDs, so following:

```
id | language | translation
---+----------+------------
 0 |       en |      Submit
 0 |       cs |     Odeslat
 0 |       fr |    Démarrer
 1 |       fr |        Jour
 1 |       en |        Day
 2 |       fr |       Lundi
 2 |       cs |     Pondělí
```

I wan't select the `translation` by `id` and sort the results by:

1. `language` = user defined language
2. `language` = 'en'

So that if there is a row with users language, it will be returned first (and only one, since I use `LIMIT`). If not, an english row will be returned, if such exists. Otherwise it does not matter.

This is what have I tried:

```
SELECT translation FROM `entries` WHERE id=1 ORDER BY language='cs' DESC, language='en' DESC LIMIT 1
```

I used `DESC` in ordering, since I assume `language='cs'` return 1 for desired rows and 0 for undesired ones.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: One would guess that the problem is, that the query above does not work. Have you tested it before asking your question? You'd find out quickly.

Comment: One would guess that if I ask that question, is because I tested it and found no problem. In your example it returns the English translation because there is no Czech translation. So instead of letting us guess, you could explain what's the difference between the query results and your expected results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa866/1

Answer (score 0):

Try CASE expression

```
SELECT *
FROM `entries` 
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN language='cs' THEN 1 
       WHEN language='en' THEN 2
       ELSE 3 
  END
```